# Seeing PHP info twice in status report

Tags: 7, status-messages

On the status report page of a drupal site we run with 7.78, the PHP version number gets reported twice.
We have only setup 1 PHP instance in IIS with version 7.3.24.

How do I correct this to pull from the right PHP instance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal.

Every module you have enabled declares its own set of requirements. In your case, it seems that one module requires a version of PHP greater than the Drupal 7 default minimum PHP version of 5.2.4. Because of this, you will see two entries in the status report:

The first entry shows you what version of PHP you are using. This is always present.

The second entry shows you a status message from one of your enabled modules. This also shows you the version of PHP you are using, but in a slightly different format. This is only present if you have a module that checks the PHP version in `hook_requirements()`.

If you want to find out which module you are using requires a non-standard PHP version, search your modules directory for `hook_requirements`. This is usually found in the `<modulename>.install` file for the module.

You will commonly see multiple entries for a variety of things. In my experience, the most common (in Drupal 7) is for cURL support - many modules require cURL, so you may see two, three, four or even more lines in the status report that tell you cURL is enabled. Again, perfectly normal.